# Passing a variables value in post request node express

Tags: node.js, post, request

Simple issue - I have a node express app that I want to perform a post request - using request passing the value of a string variable.

I don't want to transfer the name of the variable but its value.
If I just add the name to the query it will pass the actual name.

Looking forward for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how your html file will look:

```
<form method='POST' action="/signup">
            <b>USERNAME:</b> <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="yourname">
            <br>
            <br>
            <b>PASSWORD:</b> <input type="password" name="userPass" placeholder="***"><br>
            <br>
            <b>CONF. PASS.:</b> <input type="password" name="cnfPass" placeholder="***"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class = 'btn btn-primary' value="Signup">
        </form>
```

Here is how your js file will look:

```
app.post('/signup',urlencodedparser,function(req,res){
    var uPass=req.body.userPass;
    var uName=req.body.userName;
    var cnfPass = req.body.cnfPass;
    if(uPass!=cnfPass)
        res.end('Passwords dont match!')
    else
    {
        con.query("INSERT INTO USERS(name,password) values (?,?)",[uName,uPass])
        res.sendfile('user.html')
    }   
    }
)
```

You can fetch the values of the variables by assigning name to them in the html file.
In this case,
I obtain the input name value with help of 'userName' and  'userPass' fields.